# How to export Tailwind CSS result to a CSS file?

Tags: tailwind-css

I've designed my webpage using Tailwind CSS. However, as I have more than 400,000 webpages, adding the same class names everywhere would increase the final size a whole lot. Is there a way to extract the CSS rules from the class names I added in the webpage and put them in a CSS file, so that I can simply include this CSS file in all webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the CSS used in a webpage by using a browser extension and then copy all of them.

I had used this - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff?hl=en